# How do I activate a class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017

I am using a timespan that sends a test email to my email, but when I start the system it sends me nothing in the defined period.

I make um model for it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;

namespace macpartner.Models.NonFunctional
{


    public class EmailAviso
    {


        private static MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        private static readonly SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.umbler.com");
        public static void SendEmailTeste()
        {

            var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
            var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

            var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
            {
                if ((DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= System.TimeSpan.Parse("14:14:00.000") && DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay <= System.TimeSpan.Parse("14:22:00.000"))
                || (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= System.TimeSpan.Parse("16:00:00.000") && DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay <= System.TimeSpan.Parse("16:10:00.000")))
                {
                    mail = new MailMessage();

                    mail.Subject = "MacPartner - Teste Aviso";
                    mail.From = new MailAddress("macpartner@macpartner.com.br");
                    mail.To.Add("wesleyhenri.mac@gmail.com");
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    SmtpServer.Port = 587;
                    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("macpartner@macpartner.com.br", "M@cP@rtner");
                    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;



                    mail.Body = "Olá confirmação de email";



                    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                }
            },
                          null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
        }

    }

}
```

What do I have to do to activate this class?

I need to activate this class only on the server and not on all machines that enter any machine.

Comment: Could you please mention server means. Are you talking about deployment something.

Comment: I am using a Umbler web server to hoped a system developed in asp.net mvc, I connect in it by the connection string in WebConfig

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source= .\HIPER; Initial Catalog=mac; Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: I think, connection string is used for connect to the sql server not for web server.

Comment: Connection string only used for the communication with the sql server. You are in some thing wrong direction. Please little elaborate. And also i didnt get what do you mean by this "I am using a Umbler web server to hoped a system developed in asp.net mvc". What is hoped there?

Comment: Umbler's MS SQL database hosting

Comment: @WesleyHenrique Are you creating a windows service or something to send email?

Comment: Just send email because I need to send a warning email to my users at some times of the day

Comment: I will still change the warning message that the unchecked registered leads

Comment: I have found that if put in the global it keeps the application on the server, but it is not sending every few minutes that I put